# jQuery not finding all expected anchor links in HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQueryPad to try out a bit of JavaScript and I'm stuck. Given I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<TABLE style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" id=phMain_Questions class=GridView border=1 rules=all cellSpacing=0><TBODY>
<TR class=GridViewHeader>
<TH scope=col>&nbsp;</TH>
<TH scope=col>&nbsp;</TH></TR>
<TR class=GridViewRow>
<TD><A id=hlQuestionDetails href="javascript:AddQuestionWindow_Open(3, 39, 'False');">This is a test question</A> </TD>
<TD><A href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$phMain$gvQuestions$ctl02$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Remove</A> </TD></TR>
<TR class="GridViewRow GridViewRowAlt">
<TD><A id=hlQuestionDetails href="javascript:AddQuestionWindow_Open(3, 40, 'False');">This is an option question.</A> </TD>
<TD><A href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$phMain$gvQuestions$ctl03$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Remove</A> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

What I want is to pick out all the `a` tags whose `id` attribute is `hlQuestionDetails`. My stab at this is:

```
var links = $("a#hlQuestionDetails");
alert($(links).length);
```

The number of `a` tags found is 1, but as you can see in the HTML, there are in fact 2 `a` tags with that name.

Can someone point what I'm doing wrong here, as I can't figure out why jQuery is leaving one of the `a` tags out.

EDIT:

In regards to the comments, I see the problem. The HTML was generated by an ASP.NET gridview control. So instead, I should use a class attribute I guess?
Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute id should **unique** identifier of element. You should use class attribute instead.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, though I realise that others have given a similar suggestion. Didn't want to upset other users, but I had to pick one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

IDs **must** be unique in HTML, and the ID selector maps to `document.getElementById`, which returns the first matching element with that ID - give each element a `class` instead, and use the class selector:

```
var links = $("a.hlQuestionDetails");
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs have to be unique in an HTML document (hence **ID**). Most browsers only return the *first* element if there are several elements with the same ID. Use classes instead

```
<A class="hlQuestionDetails" ...>This is a test question</A>
```

and retrieve the elements with the class selector:

```
var links = $("a.hlQuestionDetails");
```

Answer (score 1):

The id should be a **unique** identifier in a html page. That's why getElementById(...) returns only 1 element. I guess jQuery does the same. Try using a *class* attribute and selector instead:

```
<a href=".." class="hlQuestionDetails">...</a>
<a href=".." class="hlQuestionDetails">...</a>
<a href=".." class="hlQuestionDetails">...</a>

alert($('a.hlQuestionDetails').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID for a tag should be unique and it should be within quotes. If you want to target several tags then use a dummy class, i.e. "Question" and then use `$('.Question')` to target your tags.